# Can I eliminate windows 8 as I install ubuntu studio?

Tags: windows-8

I can't seem to get any of the instructions online here to work.  I have yet to get Ubuntu to boot at all.  I have a new laptop with Windows 8 and I am happy to completely eliminate W8 and start fresh with Ubuntu Studio.  If you can help, send me the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to download the version you need for your machine using the torrents available on distrowatch.org and force a re-ckeck when it has completed the download to make sure it's all there...  Then burn to dvd at the slowest speed or create a bootable usb flash drive and select the option that suits you during install...  It should easily allow you to wipe the whole hard-drive with a complete install or use a single partition with the install alongside windows option...